# how to get values from admin panel to dashboard

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

hello i am trying to take all data from admin panel to the dashboard everything works well but only one filed doesnot work manytomanyfield

```
post.skillsHuman
```

not working!!!

here is code of models and views

```
class HumanSkills(models.Model):

    department = models.ForeignKey(Departments, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    human_skills = models.ManyToManyField(HumanSkills, null=False)

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name
```

this is now views

```
from .models import Document
def dashboard(request):
    context = {
        'posts': Document.objects.all()

    }
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context)
```

and this is templates

```
{% for post in posts %}
        <article class="media content-section">
         
            <img src="{{ post.image.url }}  " width="200" height="200">
            <p class="article-content">{{ post.department }}</p>
            <p class="article-content">{{ post.skillsHuman }}</p>
          </div>
        </article>
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find solution with my own, this is code how to fix that error

```
{% for skill in post.human_skills.all %}
    <p class="article-content">{{ skill }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```